# output_dir from latexmk breaks makeglossaries

Tags: glossaries, automation, latexmk, xindy

I've got a problem with a custom latexMK.rc file and makeglossaries using xindy.

The document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{API}{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={API},
    description={Application programming interface},
    first={Application programming interface (API)},
    plural={Application programming interfaces},
    firstplural={Application programming interfaces (API's)}
}

\begin{document}
    First: \gls{API}

    Second: \gls{API}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

The compile-batch:

```
latexmk -lualatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -r C:\latexmk\LatexMK.rc -pvc TEST.tex
```

The `latexMK.rc`:

```
$out_dir = 'build';
#
$pdf_mode = 4;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
#
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries {
   my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
   pushd $path;
   my $return = system "makeglossaries $base_name";
   popd;
   return $return;
}
```

The problem is shown in the picture. I tried adding `build\` to both `$path`-expressions in the `.rc`-file. Did work one time, after the first time I couldn't reproduce the behaviour.

I tried using `automake` with no effect. I also tried invoking `makeglossaries` manually - and I got the desired output.

[image: Problem shown here.]

Comment: maybe look at the automation tool ltx2any, it works well with build folders (https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any)

Comment: Since `xindy` isn't permitted in restricted mode, `automake` will required the unrestricted mode, which isn't secure. That's probably why adding `automake` didn't work. (Check the `.log` file for instances of `runsystem` to confirm.) When using `makeglossaries` you can specify the output directory with `-d`, so try `"makeglossaries -d $out_dir $base_name"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not the use of `$out_dir` but that you only defined a custom dependency for making a `.gls` file from a `.glo` file.  That's for a regular glossary.  For your document, you need to have a rule to make an `.acr` file from an `.acn` file.

To correct the problem just add the line

```
add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
```

to your `latexmkrc` file.

By the way, with the current version of `makeglossaries`, you can simplify the definition of the subroutine to

```
sub makeglossaries {
  my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
  return system "makeglossaries -d '$path' '$base_name'";
}
```

### Latexmk distribution and glossaries

Note that in the `latexmk` distribution, there is information on making it work with the `glossaries` package, in the file `example_rcfiles/glossary_latexmkrc`. Currently that focuses on the obsolete package `glossary`, and you have to read carefully to see what is the correct thing to do with the modern `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` packages.  This will be improved in the next release.

Comment: I saw your ``example_rcfiles/glossary_latexmk`` on your site. That's where I got the subroutine. I'll try your approach.

Comment: Just adding the line with ``acn`` and ``acr`` to the ``latexmkrc`` file did it. Adding the subroutine you provided did break the ``latexmk`` command. The 'old' subroutine works. Thanks for you work!

Comment: I have checked that the version of the subroutine in my answer works not only with the current versions of latexmk, makeglossaries and glossaries-extra (in TeXLive 2018), but also with the versions in TeXLive 2016.  But since the version you have works, it's not worth debugging the problem.